# Href modal redirect problem only with google chrome?

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-modal, href

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-brand btn-elevate btn-icon-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contractFiltrModal">
```

On top is my button to open my modal, but it keep redirect me to # pages instead of open my modal. This problem only occur in Google Chrome, but it works perfectly on other web browser like Safari.

If I remove href="#" in my button, the modal works but get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null at HTMLAnchorElement.".

Any solution for this?

Comment: Try using <button> tag instead of <a>

Comment: remove href  and use button tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-brand btn-elevate btn-icon-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contractFiltrModal">
  Button Name
</button>
```

[Document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/)